# Check if merge migration is required, without database

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

To check if merge migrations are required, I can run `manage.py makemigrations --check` or `manage.py makemigrations --dry-run`

However, both of those require the database to be up. If it's not up, it will error out with something like

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)")`

Theoretically, since a merge migration issue occurs because of two migration with the same parent, you don't need the database instance to be up to check for this condition.

I need this because I want my CI to check for this case. I can spin up a docker database but it's extra work for something that's not even logically dependent. I'm also sure there are people out there who are interested in checking for this in their CI, who don't want to deal with containerization.

Has anyone found an easy way to to check for migration merge conflicts without needing a database up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the goal is to run `makemigrations --dry` without a mysql database up, the easiest workaround I came up with is to create a new settings file called `makemigrations_settings.py` that overrides the database to use the builtin sqlite database.

```
from your_main_settings import *
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'database_name',
        'USER': 'your_mom',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
}
```

Then you can run

```
python manage.py makemigrations --check --settings yourapp.makemigrations_settings
```

Alternatively, you can less elegantly do something like

```
if (sys.argv[0:2] == ['manage.py', 'makemigrations']
    and ('--dry-run' in sys.argv or '--check' in sys.argv)):
            DATABASES = {
                'default' : {
                    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                    'NAME': 'database_name',
                    'USER': 'your_mom',
                    'PASSWORD': '',
                    'HOST': '',
                    'PORT': '',
                }
            }
```